# Entity groups, ReferenceProperty or key as a string

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

After building a few application on the gae platform I usually use some relationship between different models in the datastore in basically every application. And often I find my self the need to see what record is of the same parent (like matching all entry with same parent)

From the beginning I used the db.ReferenceProperty to get my relations going, like:

```
class Foo(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty()

class Bar(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty()
    parentFoo = db.ReferanceProperty(Foo)

fooKey = someFooKeyFromSomePlace
bars = Bar.all()
for bar in bar:
    if bar.parentFoo.key() == fooKey:
        // do stuff
```

But lately I've abandoned this approch since the `bar.parentFoo.key()` makes a sub query to fetch Foo each time. The approach I now use is to store each `Foo` key as a string on `Bar.parentFoo` and this way I can string compare this with `someFooKeyFromSomePlace` and get rid of all the subquery overhead.

Now I've started to look at Entity groups and wondering if this is even a better way to go? I can't really figure out how to use them.

And as for the two approaches above I'm wondering is there any downsides to using them? Could using stored key string comeback and bit me in the * * *. And last but not least is there a faster way to do this?

Comment: Is there any reason you aren't doing `Bar.all().filter("parentFoo =", fooKey)` or is this just because of your simplification for this question?

Comment: Just for the question :)

Answer (score 3):

Tip:

replace...

```
bar.parentFoo.key() == fooKey
```

with...

```
Bar.parentFoo.get_value_for_datastore(bar) == fooKey
```

To avoid the extra lookup and just fetch the key from the `ReferenceProperty`

See [Property Class](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/propertyclass.html#Property_get_value_for_datastore)

Comment: Double Tip: Use KeyProperty instead of ReferenceProperty if you're only using the value for Key comparison. https://github.com/Arachnid/aetycoon/blob/master/__init__.py

Comment: How does that avoid an extra lookup? I mean `get_value_for_datastore` does sound like an query against the DB. I might be mistaken.

Comment: `get_value_for_datastore` just fetches the `Key` which is stored within the `ReferenceProperty` itself, so no datastore RPC is required. Likewise Calvin's method avoids lookups by removing the *magicness* of `ReferenceProperty` dereferencing entirely, so it would be up to you to explicitly get related entities from the datastore without the connivence of `bar.parentFoo`

Answer (score 2):

I think you should consider this as well. This will help you fetch all the child entities of a   single parent.
    bmw = Car(brand="BMW")
    bmw.put()

```
lf = Wheel(parent=bmw,position="left_front")
lf.put()

lb = Wheel(parent=bmw,position="left_back")
lb.put()

bmwWheels = Wheel.all().ancestor(bmw)
```

For more reference in modeling. you can refer this [Appengine Data modeling](http://daily.profeth.de/2008/04/er-modeling-with-google-app-engine.html)

Comment: Nice, it will come in handy. But unfortunately I'm paring all `Bar`'s with the same parent in to there own lists. So it's a matter of checking if it has foo1 as parent it goes in to foo1List, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

When you design your modules you also need to consider whether you want to be able to save this within a transaction. However only do this if you need to use transactions.

An alternative approach is to assign the parent like so:

```
from google.appengine.ext import db

class Foo(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty()

class Bar(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty()

def _save_entities( foo_name, bar_name ):
    """Save the model data"""
    foo_item = Foo( name = foo_name )
    foo_item.put()    
    bar_item = Bar( parent = foo_item, name = bar_name )
    bar_item.put()

def main():
    # Run the save in a transaction, if any fail this should all roll back
    db.run_in_transaction( _save_transaction, "foo name", "bar name" )

    # to query the model data using the ancestor relationship
    for item in bar_item.gql("WHERE ANCESTOR IS :ancestor", ancestor = foo_item.key()).fetch(1000):
        # do stuff
```

Comment: What's the upside with using `run_in_transaction` over just invoking `_save_transaction()` ?

Comment: I have updated the code to be a bit clearer, the _save_entities() will attempt to save both Foo and Bar but if for example the Bar methods fails to save then an orphaned Foo entity remains.  When run in a transaction if either save fails then both saves will roll back, and nothing will be committed to Bigtable.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do with that example block of code, but I get the feeling it could be accomplished with:

```
bars = Bar.all().filter("parentFoo " = SomeFoo)
```

As for entity groups, they are mainly used if you want to alter multiple things in transactions, since appengine restricts that to entities within the same group only; in addition, appengine allows ancestor filters ( http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queryclass.html#Query_ancestor ), which could be useful depending on what it is you need to do.  With the code above, you could very easily also use an ancestor query if you set the parent of Bar to be a Foo.

If your purposes still require a lot of "subquerying" as you put it, there is a neat prefetch pattern that Nick Johnson outlines here: http://blog.notdot.net/2010/01/ReferenceProperty-prefetching-in-App-Engine which basically fetches all the properties you need in your entity set as one giant get instead of a bunch of tiny ones, which gets rid of a lot of the overhead.  However do note his warnings, especially regarding altering the properties of entities while using this prefetch method.

Not very specific, but that's all the info I can give you until you be more specific about exactly what you're trying to do here.

Comment: Thanks for the link, it helped out alot. The little problem I'm not sure how to be more specific. I was looking for pointers how, in some general sense, to store relations between models. And the draw backs with the different approches.